# open ball neighborhood in CW complex

Tags: general-topology, cw-complexes

In Hatcher's proof that CW complex is locally contractible (proposition A.4), he implicitly uses the fact that given a point $x \in X$, $X$ CW complex, $U$ an open neighborhood of $x$, there is an open ball of dimension $n$ called $N^n_\epsilon(x) \subset U$ for every $n$. Why is this true? I can see that this is true if $x$ lies in an $n$-cell, but for dimension $n+1,n+2,...$ I do not see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not implicit at all. He says exactly how the sets $N^n_\epsilon(x)$ are defined, half a page or so before the start of the proof of Proposition A.4.

Comment: Thank you. I found it. But now I am confused, he say he can find an open $\epsilon_\alpha$ neighborhood of $\phi^{-1}_\alpha(A) - \delta D^{n+1}$ in $D^{n+1} - \delta D^{n+1}$. How is this true? If  our cell is just the interval $[0,1]$ and $\phi^{-1}_\alpha(A)  = [0,0.5]$, then removing the boundary (point 0) from this set we cannot find an open neighborhood of this set with positive radius that lies completely inside (0,1)

Comment: Like any subset $B \subset X$ of any metric space $X$, the subset $B = \phi^{-1}(A) - \partial D^{n+1}$ of the metric space $X = D^{n+1} - \partial D^{n+1}$ has an $\epsilon_\alpha$ neighborhood in $X$, namely: $\{x \in X \mid \exists b \in B, d(x,b) < \epsilon\}$. In your example, $B = [0,0.5] \cap (0,1) = (0,0.5]$ has an $\epsilon_\alpha$ neighborhood in $X = (0,1)$, namely $\{x \in (0,1) \mid \exists b \in (0,0.5], d(x,b) < \epsilon_\alpha\}$; that neighborhood is $(0,0.5+\epsilon_\alpha)$ if $\epsilon_\alpha \le 1/2$; otherwise that neighborhood is $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you I get the construction of these neighborhood now. This still bugs me though: Hatcher claimed that he can deformation retracts $N^n_\epsilon$ onto $N^{n-1}_\epsilon$ by sliding outward along radial segments in $D^n$. I think what he means is  sliding along the rays from the center of the disk. However, I don't see why sliding along these rays we are guaranteed to hit only points on the boundary that are in N^{n-1}_\epsilon